# Docker vs VM in terms of appearing as separate device

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I want to use either multiple VMs of docker containers to mimic separate devices to use for online gambling (via Web browser).

Will docker containers appear as separate devices to websites just like a VM will?

I plan to use vpns on each instance in order to ensure the ip address is also different.

Answer (score 0):

Webservers know nothing of devices - they infer sessions based on 1 or more of a combination of factors (primarily they identify a user/device by setting a session cookie). How they do this depends on the website (panopticlick is a good site to research uniqueness).

VMs do offer better isolation but docker can certainly make environments seem unique.

BTW, this is not the first question of this nature with respect of multiple virtual PC's on gaming sites on this site. Be careful if you are pulling a scam (I think I have an inkling of what it may be). Casinos don't like looking money.